# Constructing an orthonormal basis for $L^2(\mathbb{R^2})$ with an orthonormal basis for $L^2(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be an orthonormal basis (Hilbert basis) for $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. Do the functions $(x,y) \mapsto f_n(x) f_m(y)$ form an orthonaomal basis for $L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$? Let $g(x,y) \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$. I know that $x \mapsto g(x,y)$ is a member of $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ for each $y$. So $g(x,y) = \sum_n a_n(y) f_n(x)$. If $a_n(y)$ is also in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, we can write $g(x,y) = \sum_n (\sum_m b_m f_m(y)) f_n(x)$ and the answer to my question may be yes. The problem is that I cannot show $a_n(y) \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and the uniqueness of the double series. How can I show them? Or do $f_n(x) f_m(y)$ not form a basis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have
$$
\iint_{\mathbb R^2}f_n(x)f_m(y)f_s(x)f_r(y)\,dA=\int_{\mathbb R}f_n(x)f_s(x)\,dx\,\int_{\mathbb R}f_m(y)f_r(y)\,dy=\delta_{n,s}\delta_{m,r}
$$
so your set is orthonormal. And if 
$$
\iint_{\mathbb R^2}g(x,y)f_n(x)f_m(y)\,dA=0,
$$
by Cauchy-Schwarz we may use Fubini to write, for all $n,m$, 
$$
\int_{\mathbb R}\left(\int_{\mathbb R}g(x,y)f_n(x)\,dx\right)\,f_m(y)\,dy.
$$
Then 
$$
\int_{\mathbb R}g(x,y)f_n(x)\,dx=0
$$
a.e. for all $n$. Thus $g(x,y)=0$ a.e. It follows that $\{f_n(x)f_m(y)\}_{n,m}$ is both orthonormal and total, so it is a basis.